# Multiple null in the VBA query

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am using MS Access as back end and inserting the values that are in excel trying to handle empty spaces.

```
sSQL = "Insert into " & Cells(1, 1) & " VALUES ( '" &  CStr(Cells(r, 53)) & "',' " & CStr(Cells(r, 54)) & "', '" & IIF(Isnull(Cells(r,55), "NULL",Cint(Cells(r,55)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 56)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 57)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 58)) & "','" & CInt(Cells(r, 59)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 60)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 61)) & "')"
```

For the `IIF(Isnull(Cells(r,55), "NULL",Cint(Cells(r,55))` if the cell is empty it should return NULL in the query but it is while running the query is not displaying NULL in it.

```
Insert into Test VALUES ( 'MODULE:','   Test','' ,' 0',' 0',' 0','0',' 0',' 0')
```

How can I get NULL over there. Macro is throwing an error while inserting coz there is no value for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should probably look into using `ADO` or `DAO`'s `OpenRecordSet()` to directly insert data in the database rather than constructing your SQL by hand. It will be much more robust.

However, in your case here, your `iif()` doesn't work probably because:

> `Cells(c,r)` default property `Value` is a `Variant` that returns `Empty` if the cell doesn't contain anything. It doesn't return `Null`.

So you should use `IsEmpty()` instead of `IsNull()`.

You could also use this short [`IsBlank()` VBA function](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/access-checking-blank-variables/) to make sure your test for an empty cell works as expected for various cases.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using an `ADODB.Command` parameter query from an Excel Module and it seems to work, too:

```vbs
Option Explicit

Sub AccessInsert()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandText = _
            "INSERT INTO [" & Cells(1, 1) & "] " & _
                "(FirstName, LastName, DOB) " & _
                "VALUES (?,?,?)"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDate, adParamInput)
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(3, 1)), Null, Cells(3, 1))
    cmd.Parameters(1).Value = IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(3, 2)), Null, Cells(3, 2))
    cmd.Parameters(2).Value = IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(3, 3)), Null, Cells(3, 3))
    cmd.Execute
    Set cmd = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sSQL = "Insert into " & Cells(1, 1) & " VALUES ( '" & CStr(Cells(r, 53)) & "',' " & CStr(Cells(r, 54)) & "', " & IIf(IsBlank(Cells(r, 55)), "Null", CStr(Cells(r, 55))) & ",' " & CInt(Cells(r, 56)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 57)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 58)) & "','" & CInt(Cells(r, 59)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 60)) & "',' " & CInt(Cells(r, 61)) & "')"
```

Able to get NULL in the query by using the above query along with IsBlank function.